# PHP SDK, Events. Doesn't load all event pictures at once

Tags: php, facebook, image, events, facebook-graph-api

Good day,

I have a small website http://www.incapital.lv

When I add a new event , I type in its EID. All info is transferred to my database.

Images are saved as direct links to image, e.g. http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/161932_274860499250051_1747135019_n.jpg

But when I open main page with the list of upcoming events - it doesn't load all images at once, I have to refresh page to make them all load.

What is the possible problem and how can I fix this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're fetching the images using a php resizer, and it appears that this is what's stopping the images from loading. Look at the picture Connection on the event object in Graph API for a way of directly fetching multiple image sizes: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/